# why You did not select a file to upload error occur during uploading file

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image using code igniter framework
for that my controller class code is as follows

```
public function addNewSlider()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Title','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE)
        {
            $data['content']=$this->input->get_post('content');
            $data['file']=$this->input->get_post('file');
            $data['status']=$this->input->get_post('status');

            $this->load->view('admin/templates/header',array('sessionArray'=>$this->sessionArray));
            $this->load->view('admin/sliders/addNewSlider',$data);
            $this->load->view('admin/templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            /*$title=$this->input->get_post('title');
            $content=$this->input->get_post('content');
            $image=$this->input->get_post('file');
            $status=$this->input->get_post('status');
            $this->sliders_model->insertNewMenu($title,$content,$image,$status);
            redirect('sliders','refresh');*/
        }

    }
    else
    {
        redirect('index','refresh');
    }
}
function do_upload()
{
    $name=time();
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
//  $config['max_size'] = '100';
//  $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    //$config['max_height']  = '768';
    $config['file_name']=$name;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);exit;
        //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = './uploads/'.$name.'.jpg';
    $config['new_image']    = './uploads/'.$name.'.jpg';
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['width']     = 1000;
    $config['height']   = 400;
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $config['new_image']    = './uploads/'.$name.'.jpg';
    $config['width']     = 1000;
    $config['height']   = 400;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();


    $title=$this->input->get_post('title');
    $content=$this->input->get_post('content');
    $image=$name.'.jpg';
    $status=$this->input->get_post('status');
    $this->sliders_model->insertNewSlider($title,$content,$image,$status);
    redirect('sliders','refresh');

}
**and my view file is code is as follows**

<?php echo form_open_multipart('sliders/do_upload',array('class'=>'search_form general_form'));?>
                                                <!--[if !IE]>start fieldset<![endif]-->
                                                <fieldset>
                                                    <!--[if !IE]>start forms<![endif]-->
                                                    <div class="forms">                                                     
                                                    <!--[if !IE]>start row<![endif]-->
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <label>Title:</label>
                                                        <div class="inputs">
                                                            <span class="input_wrapper"><input class="text" name="title" id="title" type="text" value="<?php //echo $title?>"/>
                                                         </span>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--[if !IE]>end row<![endif]-->

                                                    <!--[if !IE]>start row<![endif]-->
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <label>Image Path:</label>
                                                        <div class="inputs">
                                                            <!--<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> -->
                                                            <input type="file" name="file"/>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--[if !IE]>end row<![endif]-->

                                                    <!--[if !IE]>start row<![endif]-->
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <label>Content:</label>
                                                        <span class="input_wrapper textarea_wrapper">
                                                        <textarea rows="5" cols="5" class="text" name="content"><?php //echo $content?></textarea>
                                                        </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--[if !IE]>end row<![endif]-->


                                                    <!--[if !IE]>start row<![endif]-->
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <label>Status:</label>
                                                        <div class="inputs">
                                                            <span class="input_wrapper blank">
                                                                <select name="status">
                                                                <?php if(isset($_POST['status']))
                                                                {
                                                                    $one='1';
                                                                    $zero='0';
                                                                    if($_POST['status']==$one)
                                                                    { echo "InIF";?>
                                                                    <option value="1" selected="selected" >Active</option>
                                                                    <option value="0" >Inactive</option>

                                                                    <?php }else if($_POST['status']==$zero){echo "InElseIF";?>
                                                                        <option value="0" selected="selected" >Inactive</option>
                                                                        <option value="1">Active</option>

                                                                    <?php }
                                                                    } 
                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                        echo "InElse"; ?>
                                                                    <option value="1"  >Active</option>
                                                                    <option value="0"  >Inactive</option>
                                                            <?php   }?>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--[if !IE]>end row<![endif]-->

                                                    <!--[if !IE]>start row<![endif]-->
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="buttons">
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><span class="button send_form_btn"><span><span>SEND FORM</span></span><input value="upload" type="submit" /></span></li>
                                                                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>sliderTable.php" class="button uncheck_all"><span><span>Cancel</span></span></a></li>

                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--[if !IE]>end row<![endif]-->
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--[if !IE]>end forms<![endif]-->
                                                </fieldset>
                                                <!--[if !IE]>end fieldset<![endif]-->                                               
                                            </form>
```

my main problem is that while I pressing submit button error message ***You did not select a file to upload.*** displays. Can any one help me to overcome this problem quickly?

Comment: How about narrowing down the problem just a little bit for us?

Answer (score 6):

In CodeIgniter, if you are using the upload library/helper, then by default you must name your File input `userfile`.

To get around this, you can pass the name of the file input to the `do_upload` method.

i.e.

```
<input type="file" name="my_file" />

$this->upload->do_upload('my_file');
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that I'm using the CKeditor with codeignitor and you'll need to use this method when creating a custom file upload. The file input is named 'upload'.